# invalid decimal value (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, ethers.js

//List Products

```
  const listProducts = async (
    seller,
    price,
    rating,
    name,
    description,
    category,
    imgUrl
  ) => {
    if (!name || !description || !price || !rating || !category || !imgUrl) {
      alert("Pls provide necessary details");
      const contract = await connectingWithSmartContract();
      const getListedProducts = await contract.listNewProduct({
        price: ethers.utils.parseEther(price),
        rating: rating,
        name: rating,
        description: description,
        category: category,
        imgUrl: imgUrl,
      });
      alert("products listed sucessfully");
      return getListedProducts;
    } else {
      alert("something went wrong while listing products");
    }
  };
```

the error is coming from the above code maybe the price format is wrong how do i format it, im using matic as method of payment

Answer (score 1):

One of your input variables is of type BigNumber, so your code is failing to enter it in the contract. Try using the BigNumber package or send the variable in string format. Sometimes that work.

Comment: how can change to string

Comment: I guess `.toString()` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

use toString function inside `ethers.utils.parseEther(price)` like this `ethers.utils.parseEther(price.toString())` it will work.